# Connect meteor/nginx app to mongoDB with authentication

Tags: mongodb, authentication, meteor, nginx

I have a meteor app with nginx and on the same server I have a mongoDB database which have an authentication.
When I want to connect on the database in ssh, it works fine with the authentication.
But on the meteor app, I always have a 502 bad gateway error.
I think it's because the application can't connect to the database but I don't know how to connect it.
On the file `/etc/init/myapp.conf` , I change the mongo url :

```
    export MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/myapp
```

but I have always the same problem.

And in the file `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`, I have these errors :

```
[initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45266 #2680 (3 connections now open)
[conn2680] assertion 16550 not authorized for query on myapp.system.indexes ns:myapp.system.indexes query:{ ns: "myapp.users"$
[conn2680]  ntoskip:0 ntoreturn:1000
[conn2680] end connection 127.0.0.1:45266 (2 connections now open)
[initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45268 #2681 (3 connections now open)
[conn2681] assertion 16550 not authorized for query on myapp.system.indexes ns:myapp.system.indexes query:{ ns: "myapp.users"$
[conn2681]  ntoskip:0 ntoreturn:1000
[conn2681] end connection 127.0.0.1:45268 (2 connections now open)
```

When I remove the authentication in the database, it works fine, but I need this authentication.

Do you know how to connect the application to the database with authentication ?

**Update :**
In the file `/home/myapp/myapp.log`, I have :

```
Exception in setInterval callback: MongoError: not authorized for update on myapp.users
at Object.Future.wait (/home/myapp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (packages/meteor.js:213:24)
at [object Object].MongoConnection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:774:49)
at [object Object].update (packages/mongo/collection.js:581:29)
at AccountsServer.Ap._expireTokens (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1115:14)
at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1204:14
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1122:17)
at packages/meteor.js:445:45
at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor.js:1176:24)
- - - - -
at Function.MongoError.create (/home/myapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:$
at toError (/home/myapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:114:22)
at /home/myapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1047:60
at getLastErrorCallback (/home/myapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/wireprotocol/2_4_s$
at /home/theroofwebapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:455:18
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Comment: can you provide some details about the host/provider i.e. Digital Ocean or AWS etc. I have a similar set-up on Digital Ocean where in I access the MongoDB residing on another DO droplet through private IP. also share some details like MongoDB version and if its in replication mode etc. or are you trying to set this up in a local machine.

Comment: The application and the database are both on the same server on Digital Ocean (ubuntu 14.04.5 x64). The mongoDB version is 2.4.9 and I don't have replication. On a local machine, it works but when I deploy it with nginx on the Digital Ocean server, it doesn't work.

Comment: what is the meteor version are you trying to use? Although it's not related to the original query, I would recommend to upgrade Mongodb to 3.x atleast, 3.2 would be better

Comment: I use the version 1.4.2.7 of meteor.

Comment: Open a terminal and connect to the DO instance. Then open myapp.conf, copy everything between `script` and `end script` lines. Then paste the contents onto the terminal which is connected to DO and execute all lines. then check Meteor logs. for e.g. in the tutorial shared by you... instead of `>> /home/todos/todos.log` check the logs where you are rotating.

Comment: I did what you say and I have an error in the file `/home/myapp/myapp.log`.
I post the error in the update of the original post.

Comment: try connecting using terminal in CLI. ```mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/myapp -u <your_username> -p <your_password>``` If this works then within mongo cli, try `use myapp` then `show collections`. If this works, just double-check the set username and password in `/etc/init/myapp.conf`

Comment: also within the meteor project directory, try running `MONGO_URL="mongodb://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:27017/myapp" meteor`

Comment: I did `mongo myip:45475/myapp -u username -p password` and I get `Error: couldn't connect to server myip:45475 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed` but if I do `mongo myip:27017/myapp -u username -p password`, I'm connected to the database but just in the terminal.

Comment: I already tried to do `MONGO_URL="mongodb://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:27017/myapp‌​" meteor build .` but it doesn't work.

Comment: When you are trying `MONGO_URL="mongodb://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:27017/myapp‌​‌​" meteor` don't add `build`. This will just try to start the Meteor app in a developer mode.

Comment: If this is working `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/myapp -u username -p password` then post that you should be in Mongo CLI (environment). Within that, try running `use myapp` and then `show collections` let me know what's the result.

Comment: I don't have meteor on the DO instance. So I build it on my computer and I send it to the DO instance and deploy it with nginx. So, if I don't add build, I start it in localhost and it works. But when I try to build it and send it to my DO instance, it doesn't work.
When I do `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/myapp -u username -p password`, I'm connected to the database and if I do `use myapp` and `show collections` I can see all the collections I have in the database.

Comment: Within mongo environment, share the output of `db.system.users.find()`. Take care not to share sensitive data. I hope you are running all the mongo commands on DO instance and not your local.

Comment: I'm running the mongo command on the DO instance. 
If I'm connected with my_user and I do `db.system.users.find()` I have `error: {
 "$err" : "not authorized for query on myapp.system.users",
 "code" : 16550
` but if I'm connected with admin (by doing db.auth('admin', 'password')) and I do `db.system.users.find()` I have `{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ade0a3541425d73e34e280"), "user" : "my_user", "pwd" : "encrypted_password", "roles" : [  "readWrite" ] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to mongo shell and authenticate as admin and then try below

```
use admin
db.system.users.update({"user" : "your_user"}, {$addToSet: {'otherDBRoles.myapp': 'readWrite'}}, false, false)
```

*Replace your_user with your db username and myapp with the targeted database name*

Comment: On your local machine where you have Meteor installed, try running `MONGO_URL="mongodb://<user>:<password>@<DO_IP>:27017/<db_name>​‌​" meteor ` Replace DO_IP with public address of DO where Mongodb is running

Comment: If you run the command in the provided answer, then ideally you should see `{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ade0a3541425d73e34e280"), "user" : "my_user", "pwd" : "encrypted_password", "roles" : [ "readWrite" ], otherDBRoles: { myapp: [ "readWrite" ] }  }`. However, I don't see otherDBRoles when you shared output of `db.system.users.find()` earlier in comments

Comment: I did this and when I go to localhost:3000 it works and I am connected to the database on the DO instance.

Comment: So the issue seems to be only with DO instance i.e. when running the app through upstart. In myapp.conf, cross-check the DB details in export MONGO_URL. Ideally it should work. Stop the upstart service, delete the log file in `/home/todos/todos.log`, start the app and share the new logs

Comment: If I do `use admin` and  `db.system.users.find()` I have `{ "_id" : ObjectId("58adf21ed66a98891e7baadf"), "user" : "admin", "pwd" : "encrypted_password", "roles" : [  "userAdminAnyDatabase",  "dbAdminAnyDatabase",  "readWriteAnyDatabase",  "clusterAdmin" ] }` and if I do `use myapp` and  `db.system.users.find()` I have `{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ade0a3541425d73e34e280"), "user" : "my_user", "pwd" : "encrypted_password", "roles" : [  "readWrite" ] }` . So I don't have "otherDBroles".

Comment: So I check again the MONGO_URL in `myapp.conf` and it was good like before. Then I did `service nginx stop` , I deleted the log in `/home/myapp/myapp.log` and I did `service nginx start ` and `start myapp` and it works !! And I have nothing in the file `/home/todos/todos.log`. But I really don't know why...

Comment: My guess is that the mongo user was not configured correctly earlier. Also, restarting everything always helps :) Please can you accept the answer if the whole conversation and debugging helped?

Comment: @Adrien If feasible, just an advice, try upgrading MongoDB to 3.2, better performance and security. Thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things for you to double check.

1. Make sure that you are exporting `MONGO_URL` wherever you are starting your Meteor app.  You mentioned that you are doing your `export MONGO_URL` in `/etc/init/myapp.conf`.  That doesn't sound like the correct place.
2. Make sure you are actually including your real username and password in the mongodb connection string and the connection string is using the correct port where mongodb is actually running.  What you included in your question is a generic example but also included your app's name so its unclear if this is actually what you are using.
3. Double check the role you setup for the mongodb user used by your Meteor app.  Make sure you at least gave the role of `readWrite`.  Here is an example.

   ```
   db.createUser(
     {
       user: "meteor",
       pwd: "meteor",
       roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "meteor_app" } ]
     }
   );
   ```

Comment: 1. I export the `MONGO_URL` in this file because it's the configuration file of my project. I don't know where to put it if not there. And in the tutorial I follow it was here too. [link] (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx)
2. In this : ` export MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/myapp`, I have replaced "user", "password" and "myapp" with my user, password and application name.
3.I don't have roles in my users. To create them, I use the package accounts-password.

Comment: @Adrien #3 is for mongodb (not Meter accounts).  When you setup authentication in mongodb you have to create a new user and that user has to have a set of mongodb roles.  The code that I included is what you would execute in the mongodb shell to create your new user.  The bottom line is, however you created your mongodb user used by your app, ensure that they have at least the `readWrite` role for the db your app is using.